# Request within a request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, request

I am using request library in nodejs. I need to call new url within the request but I am not able to join the response as it is asynchronouse. How do I send **variable a** as in below request containing result of request within a request.

```
 request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    var a = [];
    a.push(response);
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.somecondition === "rightcondition") {
            request({
                url: url2,
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                a.push(response);
            });
        }
    }
    res.send(a);
});
```

Comment: move the res.send to underneath the second a.push. is that what you need?

Comment: @spiritwalker there is condition in second request. Edited

Comment: doesn't matter if there is condition or not, you need to make sure res.send is not triggered outside the second callback. So move res.send next to for loop

Comment: @spiritwalker as in edit , the a variable does not contain response from second request.

Comment: ok I see you edited your code again and now the second request/callback are sitting in a for loop. So that's where you actual problem is. Two options here: 1. use https://github.com/request/request-promise-native and you can do Q.all(arrayOfPromises) to resolve all responses from second request;  2. if you just want to stick on current code base, you need to count each push in second callback, so have a counter to check if(pushedCount === a.length) {res.send} else {keep pushing }; NOTE: I'm not sure if the second works with cluster mode(maybe race condition)

Comment: a quick sample to explain the option 2 I mentioned above: https://jsfiddle.net/spiritwalker/abqabhLd/

Comment: one thing about your code logic, you create an empty array a[], then pushed one item into it within your first callback, and then you loop a ??? a has only one item anyway doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems almost right for what you want. You are just sending the response in the wrong callback. Move it so it only sends after the second request has completed:

```
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    var a = [];
    a.push(response);
    request({
        url: url2,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            if(a.somecondition === "rightcondition"){
                a.push(response);
            }
        }
        res.send(a); // this will send after the last request
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually request is within for loop. My BAD !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall)

```
'use strict';

let async = require('async');
let request = require('request');

async.waterfall([function(callback) {
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        callback(error, [response]);
    });
}, function(previousResponse, callback) {
    request({
        url: url2,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        for(i=0;i<previousResponse.length;i++){
          if(previousResponse.somecondition === "rightcondition"){
            previousResponse.push(response);
         }
        }
        callback(error, previousResponse);
    });
}], function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send('Request failed');
    }
    // the results array will be final previousResponse
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
});
```